# Free tool for removing noise green background from a portrait foto

Tags: photography, image-editor

I took a photo that I really like and would like to use for my CV (my current avatar). Unfortunately, it has a green nature background that could be perceived as unprofessional. Which free tool that either runs online or on Windows 10 does the best job at removing the background? It's okay if I need to spent five minutes for it.

Comment: It is generally considered not to be a good idea to put a photo  on a CV. See, for instance, [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/58381/should-i-provide-my-photo-id-to-a-recruiter) and others on our sister site. I upvoted your question, though :-)

Answer (score 1):

> Whether you are a graphic designer, photographer, illustrator, or
>   scientist, [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/) provides you with sophisticated tools to get your job
>   done. You can further enhance your productivity with GIMP thanks to
>   many customization options and 3rd party plugins.

In your case here are some example pages:

https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tutorial-quickie-separate.html

http://gimptips.com/articles/removing-image-backgrounds-gimp-fuzzy-select[enter link description here](http://gimptips.com/articles/removing-image-backgrounds-gimp-fuzzy-select)

Comment: Those example pages don't help given that they are about objects with clear borders and not the kind of boundaries that the hair on my image has.

Comment: @Christian you didn't provide any information about photo with hair. GIMP is the free / open source replacement of Photoshop. I don't think you can accomlish what you want without one of these tools and some technical knowledge. You need to use an image editor and search for how to remove background. (This is a dirty fix)

Comment: I did, I said that I care about a portrait photo and that's a category of photos that includes hair. I even said that I care about a very specific photo, the one I'm currently using as avatar.

Comment: Gimp 2.10 improved a lot the [foreground select](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-foreground-select.html) tool to be able to include hair. But you should spend some more time. Five minutes is enough for ok-ish result, but not for very good result.